# You do not have permission to access error in all the images in magento 1.9.3.4?

Tags: magento-1.9, database, ce-1.9.0.1, ce-1.9.1.0, ce-1.9.2.2

product images, Logo, etc any images which are using on the website, is not showing when I open images in new tab, error is showing
`You don't have permission to access /media/product/afd/adc145.png on this server.
Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request`

I have checked the permission of all the folder which is related to images, all folders have 0777 permission.

Kindly help to resolve this issue

Comment: If you are using Apache, please post your `.htaccess` file.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs because of proper permission. can you please check permission for your server. The below is Magento recommend. Please try like this

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 400 {} \;
find . -type d -exec chmod 500 {} \; 
find var/ -type f -exec chmod 600 {} \; 
find media/ -type f -exec chmod 600 {} \;
find var/ -type d -exec chmod 700 {} \; 
find media/ -type d -exec chmod 700 {} \;
```

for more information check

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/install/installer-privileges_after.html

Comment: i have checked all the permission is correct. all the  images of both admin & front-end are not showing.

Comment: can you provide website url i will check and come to solution